# How to change the color of the button and make it disable after clicking once in odoo?

Tags: button, colors, formatting, odoo, disable

I am sending invitation to user by clicking *Invite* button. I want that after sending invitation button should un-clickable and its color also change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide that button with conditions.

For example, if you have two states `draft,invitation_sent`, by default the form will open in draft state. Once you click the button, change the state to `invitation_sent`. And hide the button in the `inivtation_sent` state.

Code example:

In Python:

`````````````````````````````````
def invite(self):
    ````````````````````````````````
    ````````````````````````````````
    ````````````````````````````````
    self.write({'state': 'inivtation_sent'})
`````````````````````````````````

In XML:

```
<button name="invite" type="object" string="Invite" class="oe_highlight" attrs="{'invisible':[('state','=','inivtation_sent')]}"/>
```

Comment: What if I want to change its string value?

Comment: @adamStrauss Please elaborate the question with code.

Comment: Ok let me try.
As you mentioned above how to make button invisible after sending invitation. Now i am asking that after clicking Invite button how to change the text/string of button into Invited text/string.

Comment: define the state as the status bar and give the string value of 'inivtation_sent' as Invited.